# Should I add System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations as reverence .net 48

Tags: c#, .net

I have a .Net48 project and in my project was a reference to

```
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
```

But after removing it I was able to successfully build my project.
Do I need to still have this reverence in the *.csproj file?

Also, I see that I have an implicit reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.
What does it mean?

And do I need to use a package reference System.ComponentModel.Annotations (not System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations) after migration to net6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were able to successfully build your project without an explicit reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, you do not require it. Some other packages might require this package but this does not mean that you will need to manually reference it.

If you reference packages that depend on other packages, you are implicitly referencing those other packages.